# Can we rederive the topological structure of a space from the category of continuous paths?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

If we have a topological space $(X,T)$, then we can define the category $(X,P)$, where $P$ are morphisms between objects in $X$ such that the homset $Hom(a,b)$ is the set of all continuous (according to $T$) paths between $a$ and $b$ in $X$.

Can we rederive $T$ from $P$? i.e. does the category of continous paths on $X$ completely determine the topological structure on $X$?

Comment: While it doesn't really affect Henno's answer, it's worth mentioning that there is no obvious category such as you describe. Normally one takes the category whose morphisms are homotopy classes of paths instead, since it's easier to define an associative composition and since this is a groupoid, called the fundamental groupoid. It's possible to construct a category along your lines only by a construction like the Moore loop space, which makes the loop space multiplication strictly associative.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I don’t see why the category I described is problematic. Just take composition is defined by just connecting the paths. This connection is obviously associative. There are identities obvioiusly. So its a category.

Comment: It's because usually the interval on which paths are defined is fixed as $[0,1]$, and so concatenation is not associative (it is only associative up to homotopy). But I'm guessing you're allowing the defining interval to change ?

Comment: @Max yeah you can either allow the definining interval to change to any $[0,a]$ or take equivalence classes up to monotonic transformations of the lines.

Comment: @user56834 There are certainly solutions, as you suggest, but I was just complaining that you didn't specify one, and there is no preferred one. Both of your solutions end up with a non-groupoid and (thus) retain a lot of uninteresting information like distinguishing between a path followed by the reversed path and a constant path.

Answer (score 4):

If $X$ is totally disconnected (and there are *many* of those that are topologically distinct, like $\mathbb{Q}$, the irrationals, the Cantor set etc.) all have the property that $\textrm{Hom}(I,X)$ (where $I$ the closed unit interval) is just a set of constant functions. So the paths into $X$ contain no real topological information on $X$ (just its size: the number of constant paths).

Any "paths" from a connected space is not enough information...